# How to repeat trigger in a logic analyzer

Tags: logic-analyzer

I'm using *OpenBench Logic Sniffer* (HW) with *Sigrok PulseView* (SW) to reverse engineer some binary UART communication between a control panel and the device. The trouble is that I can capture only 24k samples at 500kHz which is fine for the first packet. But the subsequent comms happens sometime later, sometimes up to 1 second later, by that time the logic analyzer buffer fills up and I never get to capture the second packet.

I can use a lower sampling rate, say 10kHz and can see the second packet, but at 10kHz the captutred data is rubbish and useless for decoding.

[image: PulseView screenshot]

Is there any way to set the trigger to re-arm for example 100ms after the start of the first communication and then wait for the next packet? I can't really do it by hand because the intervals are varied.

TL;DR what I need is capture the second packet at 1200ms at 500kHz and wait for the trigger again after the first packet is complete.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: If the packets repeat (say after a button press) then start capture1 , press button.  Save first result.  Then press button, wait 0.5s and start capture 2, then save that as second result.

Comment: If you know it's UART you might consider connecting an actual UART receiver which might be easier to use than a logic analyzer